# What microcontroller can connect directly to a USB port?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

Essentially, I just need to send some data to the microcontroller via USB, then the microprocessor decodes the data and drives an LED light strip, which runs at 5V. I'm having trouble finding the right microcontroller for the job.

The microcontroller just needs to have 2 serial in ports for USB communication, two serial out ports for communication with the LED strip, and be able to operate at 5V. It seems unnecessary to have a dedicated IC for USB communication when all I need is a serial COM port set up.

For example, here is the snippet of Arduino code that writes a byte to the LPD8806 strip:

```
void write8(uint8_t d) {
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++) {
    if (d & _BV(7-i))
      digitalWrite(dataPin, HIGH);
    else
      digitalWrite(dataPin, LOW);
   digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW); 
  }
}
```

To latch the data you send zeros to the strip.

Comment: I think you mean one USB connection (they're two way), and one serial connection (also two way).  If you're into pic, the 18f4550 family will do the job.

Comment: What's the protocol for the LED strip? Can you add a link to the datasheet or web site of the strip?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet Its this LED [Strip](http://learn.adafruit.com/digital-led-strip/overview). The datasheet is in chinese, however there is simply a serial in and clock in, and you latch by sending zeros down the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that by "two serial out ports" you mean one UART (since you also describe USB as 2 ports). *Rocketmagmet* indicates that many/most LED strings use SPI, but that will need at least 3 wires. Can you specify which protocol you need?

In general Microchip has the lowest cost microcontrollers, also this time. *And* Microchip has many microcontrollers in DIL package as well, while many others have ditched that. May be important for DIY. The [PIC18F13K50](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41350E.pdf)

- exists in both DIL-20 and SMT packages
- works at 5 V (for interfacing with the LED strip)
- is low cost at $2.5 (OK, that's relative, but USB able controllers *are* a bit more expensive than more basic types)
- has Enhanced USART for UART interface
- has an SPI interface in case you meant that
- has 25 mA source and sink I/O, so you can directly drive a couple of indicator LEDs if needed

**Further reading**
[USB Generic Function on an Embedded Device](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01166a.pdf), Microchip Application Note AN1166

Comment: He mentions LED strips, so I assume it's a synchronous protocol (basically SPI without the data return pin). That PIC only has 1 SPI port, so wouldn't be suitable. Although he could bit bang the protocol.

Comment: @Rocket - where does he say it's SPI? And he won't need two SPI buses: SPI is multi-slave. And like Scott commented and I also said at the start of my answer, I think by two ports he means two pins, that's why I thought about UART first.

Comment: Perhaps the PIC18F24J50? But it's a 3.3v part, so I don't know if it will interface to the LED strip.

Comment: He doesn't say it's SPI, but I have used LED strips before, and they have always been synchronous. I could be wrong. He might mean another kind of LED strip that I've never seen before. I think he means two pins for clock & data.

Comment: Actually, I mis-read the question and thought he said two LED strips! He actually said two pins for one LED strip. So, er, as you were with the original suggestion.

Comment: @Rocket - I found a couple of LED string controllers [which use SPI](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/HL1606E.pdf), but also one which uses a one-wire protocol. SPI makes sense since it's the most basic synchronous thing, especially is you don't need the MISO feedback.

Comment: The strip is not quite SPI. The ICs on the strip are LPD8806, which operate with only a DI and CI. [Here](http://learn.adafruit.com/digital-led-strip/overview) is the strip in question.

Comment: @SteveBarna - You're right, it's not quite SPI. But when we say SPI, we mean that you'd use the SPI module on the PIC, rather than the UART module. The PIC Steven mentioned will be fine if you only want one LED strip. If you want more than 1, you can either chain them, or use a PIC (or PSoC) with more SPI ports.

Comment: Not that OP's application needs it, but as far as I know, there are no High-Speed USB PICs.

Comment: @ajs410 - Doesn't surprise me at all. You can't clock 480 Mbps of data with an 80 MHz clock. You'll find High-Speed USB only on high-end controllers like ARM Cortex-A9, which can run at clocks up to 2 GHz (dual core version).

Comment: @stevenvh would you consider the Cypress FX2 to be "high end"?  It's an 8051 microcontroller with High-Speed USB support that uses a 24 MHz crystal.  Sure, it uses a PLL to handle the 480 Mbps, the USB PIC24F's also use a PLL.

Comment: @ajs410 - At $15 for a ROMless part, yes, that's high end :-). I don't understand some people: they want to build a power full controller/SoC (which you need to process 60 MB of data per second), and then they put a stinking 8051 in it...

Comment: Ah, see, I wouldn't consider a 48 MHz 8-bit QFP microcontroller to be high end...when I think high end, I think several 100s of MHz, at least 16-bit, and probably BGA.  And for what it's worth, the 8051 in an FX2 isn't supposed to be the consumer of data, it's supposed to be used in concert with an "external master" that can source and sink that much data.

Answer (score 4):

Your LED strip has a simple serial interface.  If you are just trying to control it with a computer, you can use a FTDI chip to wiggle the pins: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm

Then the complexity is on the PC side using [libftdi](http://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/) or [D2XX](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) libraries. But it's not too bad, similar complexity to your Arduino example.

If you don't feel like making hardware, you can purchase premade cables with the FTDI chip from FTDI distributors like Mouser, or from Sparkfun etc.  Cables are available in different voltage configurations, so order carefully.

Of course, if you want the project to be standalone or autonomous somehow, you will want a full microcontroller solution.

Comment: I should consider sending raw SPI data to the LED strip via a USB Controller. Microchip makes a USB-to-SPI which sets itself up as a HID device, while FTDI chips are either VCOM or D2XX and i'm not sure which would best suit running a light strip from a c++ program yet.

Comment: I'm not aware of an USB<->SPI bridge that shows up as a virtual serial port like the USB<->UART bridge chips do.  Instead you will have to write bit-banging code, which is easy for SPI.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the [PSoC3](http://www.cypress.com/?id=2232).

[image: PSoc3]

They are available with USB, and almost any peripherals you want. (They are configured in software) You'll certainly be able to have two serial ports for the LED strips. You'll probably be able to have 20 if you want.

The development environment is also a joy to use.

[image: PSoC Creator]

Comment: Well that seems a bit overkill. But i'll look into it.

Comment: @Rocket - I see on Digikey that a PSOC costs more than twice the PIC I mentioned. I don't doubt they're worth their weight in gold (as a figure of speech), *if* you need all those configurable peripherals, for solutions you won't find on any other microcontroller, like 16 UART or so. But OP seems to need just a USB port and a serial port (UART, SPI, or I2C), then it's *much* cheaper to pick a relatively low-end controller which has just that.

Comment: @stevenvh - I agree, the PSoCs can be painfully expensive. They're only really worth it for production when you can take advantage of their many functions. But for prototyping, they're *totally* worth it. You never have to go hunting for that special PIC that has just the right combination of peripherals, and you can implement *hardware* changes at the click of a button!

Comment: @Rocket - " implement hardware changes at the click of a button". Yes, that's what the Cypress guys kept telling me. I don't get it (I discussed this extensively with my colleagues, and they don't either): If I need for instance a timer in my application chances are that I need it all the time, not throw it out for a while because I want to do something different with the hardware. I *do* appreciate the configuration tools, like in your screenshot, and I've begged Motorola (before they became Freescale) a rhousand times to add a small FPGA to their HC05 controllers, but that was not...

Comment: @Rocket -(continuing)... for in-application reconfiguring, that was to have a more flexible controller *during development*. We were a big Motorola customer at the time, and they consulted with us for ideas how to clean up the HC05 mess; there were hundreds of different types, some more successful than others. So I suggested 1)the FPGA, and/or 2) a crosspoint switch array to let you connect selected peripherals to (limited) I/O; the hardware was on the die anyway. Neither happened, and Motorola doesn't make controllers anymore...

Comment: I have used hardware reconfigurability several times, and been very glad for it. It saved a complete re-spin. In one case I'd messed up the circuit for a sensor. I thought the signal would have a range of several volts, but actually had a small peak to peak voltage with a large offset. Luckily I was able to use the PSoC's DAC and PGA to offset the voltage and amplify it. This would have been impossible to do in software on most other MCUs.

Comment: In another case, a customer asked my if they could produce PWM on some digital outputs on a device I had made for them. That had not been in the original spec. No problem, I just added 4 PWM components and ORed the outputs with the original digital outputs signals so that they could easily choose to use either. Again, this would have been impossible with practically any other MCU.

Comment: But the main advantage is to be able to do things that no other MCU can do. For example, where can I find an MCU that can drive 5 H-bridges (all 4 lines, not just PWM), with synchronised mid-cycle current sampling of each channel in turn with results automatically DMAd to memory, *and* 5 quadrature decoders, *and* 2 SPI?

Comment: On the price side of things, Cypress has now released the PSoC 4 range, which is significantly cheaper than the PSoC 3 and PSoC 5, being comparable to cheaper Atmel/Microchip/TI microcontrollers.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot get simpler than this: **ATmega8U2**.

To top it off, you can even use that with Arduino bootloader...

Datasheet: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc7799.pdf

(sorry for being a bit concise, I'm typing from phone)

Comment: When you're back behind your PC (shouldn't that be "in front of"?) can you elaborate: how is this the most simple solution? It has to be a good story :-), since the ATmega8U2 is 50 % more expensive than the PIC.

Comment: I favor the AVR line (esp. ATmega) because one can use the Arduino environment for quick prototyping (poster is familiar with that!), and allows quick testing-fixing cycles. Then I optimize the code manually, or even use a smaller AVR uC, like Tiny2313 (BTW, there are soft-USB libs for AVRs). I wanted to like PICs, but when I looked at them (just before Arduino took off), I chose the AVRs: I found their docs to be better and the community stronger - despite that here in Hungary, PICs are historically more supported. I would choose a shorter dev.cycle to lower cost in low volume production.

Comment: Exactly why the downvote? Care to explain?